# Multipart Entity for perl for attaching a file through API not working

Tags: perl, api, attachment, multipart

I have the following code and want to attach a file using an API. This code is delivering me the URL but the file is not getting attached.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent; 
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post(Content_Type => 'application/xml');
#$ua->agent("Mozilla 8.0 blah...");

use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent(POST);

my $request=(POST "http://Server/Test.jsp", 
Content =>[
        external => "false",
        Filedata => "C:/Location.jpg"
          ]);

#$request = $ua->request($request);
my $results=$ua->request($request);
$content = $request->content; 


print $content; 
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you have to specify the correct content-type.

```
my $request=(POST "http://Server/watson/api/bug/addAttachmentAPI.jsp", 
Content_Type => 'form-data',
Content =>[
        appGUID => "Test GUID",
```

Second, the file specification must be an array reference of the form `[ $file, $name, ... ]` where `...` are optional header field/value pairs (if you don't include headers, the content-type of the file will be guessed).

```
        Filedata => ["C:Test Location/Upload/APIs.jpg", 'APIs.jpg'],
  ]);
```

See [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Request::Common) for more information.